# adding values from two columns tied to two other columns (where values repeat) in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to figure out the top team scorer in a df.

But how do I add values of columns "home_score" and "away_score" for teams with same names in the columns "home_team" and "away_team". Note: the team names repeat in the rows in both team columns. I've looked at dictionary, concatenate, sum... and now i'm just confused.

**home_team    away_team    home_score    away_score**

```
  A            D            3          5
  B            C            1          0
  C            B            2          1
  D            A            3          5
  A            B            3          5
```

In the above example, the output should be team A with 11 (3+3+5). How would I find an answer in a df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all score data.

```
import collections

score_data = collections.defaultdict(int)
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    score_data[row[0]] += row[2]
    score_data[row[1]] += row[3]
```

To get the highest achiever, you may do the following trick for finding maximum.

```
top_team, top_score = max((t, s) for s, t in score_data.items())
```

Comment: Thank you, kate-melnykova! It worked. I'm going to learn more "collections"